# Having localized pagination in DevExpress printpreview

Tags: c#, printing, localization, pagination, devexpress

I'm trying to have a localized pagination in the footer of all my pages in my print preview. I set my paging this way :

```
var PageOfPages = "[Page # of Pages #]";
//On n'a pas vraiment le choix de faire ça pour que ça fonctionne dans les différentes langues... :
//http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ48170.aspx
switch (CultureManager.GetInstance().TwoLetterISOCultureName)
{
  case "fr":
        PageOfPages = "[Page # de pages #]";
        break;
  case "es":
        PageOfPages = "[Página # de Páginas #]";
        break;
}
var PageHeaderArea = new PageHeaderArea();
PageHeaderArea.Content.AddRange(new[] { "", "", "[Image 0]" });
var HeaderFooter = (PageHeaderFooter)LinkBase.PageHeaderFooter;
   HeaderFooter = new PageHeaderFooter(
   PageHeaderArea,
   new PageFooterArea(new[] { dateString, "", PageOfPages }, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, BrickAlignment.Far)
);
```

It works in english, but not in french or spanish. Tried with XtraPrinting Resources dll too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the designer itself and its localization process in order to handle this, alterations directly in the code shouldn't be necessary.

To access the localizations in the designer, you open the report in design mode, and from there one of the properties is Language.  Changing that will create new .resx files which contain the localized resource strings.  That should automatically import the correct resource file, based on the users "CurrentUICulture" `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.  It all works automatically on my system.

This is assuming however that you have all the structures defined in the designer.  this wont work with code generated controls.

for those...you really want to handle it manually...

Inside the BeforePrint event you should be able to check the `CurrentUICulture` against whatever you are looking for, and alter the text of various controls accordingly.

If you dont want to do that during the reports runtime, but instead during the declaration itself, then your code should be working.  I would check to see that you are referencing the correct value in the switch statement.  You should be looking for the `CurrentUICulture` from the running thread.  I am unsure if `CultureManager.GetInstance()` will actually get you the correct value for that.

**Update: Added code example**

Use this value for the switch:

```
switch( System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOCultureName )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: actually my switch isn't the problem. If I set my application in french. in the print preview it will show `[Page # de pages #]` instead of `Page 1 de 7`. this works perfectly in english but in french or spanish. It shows the `[Page # de pages #]` or `[Página # de Páginas #]` thing at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
using DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Localization
PreviewLocalizer.GetString(PreviewStringId.PageInfo_PageNumberOfTotal)
```

this should give you the correct format string for your set language.

--reinhard